# How to center horizontally divs inside another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center div's inside one outter div, but I can't.

My html is something like this :

```
<div class="outterDiv">
  <div class="innerDivBig">
    <div style="width: 180px; float:left;margin-right: 5px;background-color: yellow;">
      Inner Div
    </div>
    <div style="width: 180px; float:left;margin-right: 5px;background-color: yellow;">
      Inner Div
    </div>
    <div style="width: 180px; float:left;margin-right: 5px;background-color: yellow;">
      Inner Div
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my css is something like this :

```
.outterDiv{
 width: 600px;
 border: 1px solid #f00;
 text-align: center;
}

.innerDivBig{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:table;
}
```

Here is [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/2a8514nf/).

Comment: left:50%; margin-left: -90px;

Comment: Are you trying to fit all 3 divs centered under each other or side by side?

Comment: I want that they are side by side. That's why there is float left.

Answer (score 1):

```
.outterDiv{
 width: 600px;
 border: 1px solid #f00;
 text-align:center;
}

.innerDivBig{

  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2a8514nf/7/

Comment: Is there any way that the fourth one is left, and not in the middle? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a8514nf/2/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2a8514nf/7/

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
https://jsfiddle.net/2a8514nf/4/

I use `display: table` because the browser calculates the width to fit all the child elements width `display: table-cell` so that you wont have to worry about the width.
I also use `padding` instead of `margin` since it does not expand the element so the parent size remains the same.

```css
.outer {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner > div {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner > div > div {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #00F;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div>
            <div>Inner Div 1</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>Inner Div 2</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>Inner Div 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need that the inner div's have fixed width.

Comment: @Boky I've updated your JSFiddle and my answer.

Comment: And if I have fourth one, can it be left positioned instead of in the middle? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a8514nf/5/)

Comment: It would like like this https://jsfiddle.net/2a8514nf/6/ Is this what you want?